# Mobile device issue after deploying a react app ( background blank )

Tags: reactjs, mobile, deployment, netlify

Im building a simple portfolio in the component "About me" the first time i added a background like stars moving and all it was working on my mobile device after deploying it but when i added some text elements to it all the background went blank . But on desktop it works all fine here are some pictures on the desktop device [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aMIu.png); and here is for the mobile device : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f9Qm.jpg) .

Any assumptions, tips , solutions anything helps

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.